# A Poisson EM clustering algorithm in R?

Tags: r, expectation-maximization

I've been looking for a Poisson expectation-maximization clustering implemented in R.  Does anyone know if there is one available or can point me in the right direction?

thanks!

and please let me know if there's a better way/place to ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try the R package `rebmix` which implements EM algorithm for mixtures of Poisson distributions :
http://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/web/packages/rebmix/vignettes/rebmix.pdf